# Can a child process be made to run on a new terminal

Tags: linux

On linux, is it possible that I create a child process and make it run on a new terminal. That is, is it possible that the parent is running on a different terminal and the child process is running on a separate terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using xterm

`xterm -e [your program]`

See http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm

Comment: I used gnome-terminal and it worked perfectly fine. But now when in the child process I checked the ppid, I found that the parent process is gnome-terminal.

Comment: I used gnome-terminal and it worked. But now when in the child process I checked the ppid, I found that the parent process is gnome-terminal. Here is the par code :                        `main() {
    char str[100] ;
    if(fork()) {
        wait() ;
    }
    else {
        char *args[] = {"gnome-terminal", "-e", "ch hi", NULL} ;
        execvp("gnome-terminal", args) ;
    }
}
`                                                                and the child code is                                       `main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("ch starts with %s\nenter str:::", argv[1]) ;
}`